# gRPC sending repeated field efficiently to server

Tags: grpc

I've a need to send batch of logs to server, but this log can be huge amount batch, for example 10k rows. I'm currently using repeated, but I realize repeated is taxing on memory for client side. Is there any way I could send in stream of logs together with my other parameter?

I'm currently coding in Dart, and can't figure out anyway to stream "logs" from client side to server. Is there any way I could use stream as a field to grpc server?

This is my sample .proto file

```
service Logger {
  //
  // Obtains the Features available within the given Rectangle.  Results are
  // streamed rather than returned at once (e.g. in a response message with a
  // repeated field), as the rectangle may cover a large area and contain a
  // huge number of features.
  rpc saveLogs(SaveLogsRequest) returns (DummyResult) {}

}

message DummyResult {
  bool success = 1;
  string error = 2;
}

message SaveLogsRequest {
  string country = 2;
  string app = 3;
  repeated Log logs = 4;
}
```

Comment: https://grpc.io/docs/languages/dart/basics/#client-side-streaming-rpc

Comment: @DazWilkin that is server to client streaming, not what im looking for

Comment: The link shows how to stream messages from a client to a server. There's a separate section for streaming messages from a server to a client. You may use a combination of both too. This is how to solve your problem.

Comment: yes i saw that sample code, but it is to send stream of points to server. problem is, ive a structured data where the repeated / stream is one of the field, not the only parameter

Comment: If the client receives the logs as a batch (of logs), you could unwrap the message on the client and stream one (or some smaller batch of) logs to the server. If the client is able to receive the log lines as they're produced, then you could stream them (on receipt) to the server.

Comment: hi @DazWilkin yes, but how do i stream as part of a field

Comment: You cannot. You can only stream a message type repeatedly. So, assuming your client can keep up, you create a stream and then, on receipt of every log, you stream a `SaveLogsRequest` containing a single (not-repeated) `Log`. This is inefficient. So I recommend you batch them up and stream x `Log` at a time. You still open a stream but now your `SaveLogsRequest` contains x `Log` entries each time you ship a message. Make sense? You could do even better and dynamically resize the number of `Log` in each message to control the flow (so that neither your client nor the server becomes overwhelmed).

Comment: hi @DazWilkin can i send in 2 grpc requests? 1 to send without repeated logs, and another one just to stream logs to server with some kind single field in log that indicate which batch it is?

Comment: You could but I think that would get complicated as you need to reconcile IDs with batches and, more of a challenging, deal with repeated batches and  missing batches. I'm tempted to write you a prototype but I'm in the middle of my own project. You need only change your rpc to include `stream`, i.e. `rpc saveLogs(stream SaveLogRequest) returns (DummyResult) {}`

Comment: if i stream savelogrequest, but i could only send 1 time with the repeated/stream field?

Comment: See "Answer" for a proof-of-concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://github.com/DazWilkin/dart-grpc-logger

My Dart skills are almost non-existent. This is a very basic, working example.

The code is derived from Google's `route-guide` sample and is here:

https://github.com/DazWilkin/dart-grpc-logger/blob/master/dart/client.dart

The server (and a second client) are written in Golang.

In one terminal, run the server:

```sh
docker run \
--interactive --tty \
--publish=50051:50051 \
dazwilkin/dart-grpc-logger-server:84a06d9cc166692ddf00c941856c96e853594695
```

> **NOTE** While the server can be reconfigured to run on any available port --grpc_endpoint=..., the Dart client requires localhost:50051 because my Dart skills are limited.

The server starts, then pauses on a client:

```
2020/06/05 20:49:36 [main] Starting gRPC Logger Server
2020/06/05 20:49:36 [main] Creating a gRPC Server
2020/06/05 20:49:36 Starting gRPC Listener [:50051]
```

In another terminal, run the client:

```sh
docker run \
--interactive --tty \
--net=host \
dazwilkin/dart-grpc-logger-client:84a06d9cc166692ddf00c941856c96e853594695
```

> **NOTE** The client must `--net=host` to be able to access the containerized server.

The client connects to the server and streams 10 randomly-sized batches of logs:

```
[Client:main] Entered
[Client:main] Configuring channel
[Client:main] Creating gRPC Logger Client
[Client:runSaveLogs] Entered
[Client:generateLogs] Count=10
[Client:generateLogs] Batch=1
[Client:generateLogs] Batch=4
[Client:generateLogs] Batch=4
[Client:generateLogs] Batch=4
[Client:generateLogs] Batch=7
[Client:generateLogs] Batch=8
[Client:generateLogs] Batch=7
[Client:generateLogs] Batch=7
[Client:generateLogs] Batch=8
[Client:generateLogs] Batch=9
[Client:runSaveLogs] Finished
```

The server receives the stream of batches of logs:

```
2020/06/05 20:49:47 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:47Z Entered
2020/06/05 20:49:48 [Server:SaveLogs] Received 1 logs
2020/06/05 20:49:48 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:48Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:48 [Server:SaveLogs] Received 4 logs
2020/06/05 20:49:48 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:48Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:48 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:48Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:48 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:48Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:48 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:48Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:48 [Server:SaveLogs] Received 4 logs
2020/06/05 20:49:48 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:48Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:48 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:48Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:48 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:48Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:48 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:48Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:48 [Server:SaveLogs] Received 4 logs
2020/06/05 20:49:48 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:48Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:48 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:48Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:48 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:48Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:48 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:48Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] Received 7 logs
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] Received 8 logs
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] Received 7 logs
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] Received 7 logs
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:49 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:49Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] Received 8 logs
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:50Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:50Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:50Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:50Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:50Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:50Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:50Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:50Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] Received 9 logs
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:50Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:50Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:50Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:50Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:50Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:50Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:50Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:50Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:50Z Log: test
2020/06/05 20:49:50 [Server:SaveLogs] 2020-06-05T20:49:50Z EOF
```

Comment: thats exactly what ive done, and im looking for streaming repeated logs, not addAll logs. but thanks for the afford :)

Comment: This does stream. It streams batches (of >=1 logs). In practice, I think you'd always have batches to cache between your log generator and this client. If you don't have batches but want to stream each log line, then just have a batch size of 1. Good luck!

Comment: oh your are making whole SaveLogsRequest stream, so this will also stream the field logs